# Changing the icon-theme for the desktop

Tags: 19.10, desktop-icons

How can I change the icon-theme on the desktop on Ubuntu 19.10 ?
Now I have fat black icons on the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the icon theme in Ubuntu with Gnome Shell (version 17.10 and upwards), you need to install an external configuration tool, "Gnome Tweaks". On the "Appearance" tab, you can select one of the installed icon themes on your system.

Comment: Yes I tried it, but only part of the icons change. Directory, junk,and personal directory and some more stay "heavy black"

Comment: Perhaps you should post a screenshot. What I indicated is the standard way to change icon themes as you asked.